# Binding objects not working outside FXML UI controller initialize() method

Tags: java, javafx

**Core problem**: `Binding` objects invalidation listeners are not triggered if bound properties are updated outside the `initialize()` method where they are declared.

Take this `initialize()` method declared in a JavaFX UI controller class:

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    final StringProperty stringProperty = textField.textProperty();
    stringProperty.addListener(
            (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println("stringProperty value: " + newValue));
    Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> "PREFIX - " + stringProperty.getValue(), stringProperty).addListener(
            (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println("StringBinding value: " + newValue));

    // Editing stringProperty value inside initialize() method
    stringProperty.setValue("u");
    stringProperty.setValue("ua");
    stringProperty.setValue("ua");
    stringProperty.setValue("uaa");
}
```

As you can see there I declare a `StringBinding` that depends on the text property of a TextField, called `stringProperty`, and a `ChangeListener` that requests the compute of the `StringBinding` when it gets invalid.

If I edit `stringProperty` value inside the initialize method both `stringProperty` and `StringBinding` change listeners are triggered, while if I edit the `stringProperty` value from the UI only the `stringBinding` change listener is triggered.

Can someone explain me why this happens?

Comment: Since there's no strong reference to the `StringBinding` created by `Bindings.createStringBinding` it is eventually garbage collected.

Comment: I don't think that this is the point because `Binding` object listen to their dependencies (`Observable` objects) by an `InvalidationListener`, and the `Obsevable.addListener(InvalidationListener)` documentation states that "The Observable stores a strong reference to the listener which will prevent the listener from being garbage collected and may result in a memory leak."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no strong references to the `StringBinding` created by `Bindings.createStringBinding` exist it is eventually being garbage collected. Once that happens, the listener you added will be garbage collected along with it.

> I don't think that this is the point because `Binding` object listen to their dependencies (`Observable` objects) by an `InvalidationListener`, and the `Obsevable.addListener(InvalidationListener)` documentation states that "The Observable stores a strong reference to the listener which will prevent the listener from being garbage collected and may result in a memory leak."

This is true, but take a look at the listener implementation the `XXXBinding` classes use:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2011, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 * DO NOT ALTER OR REMOVE COPYRIGHT NOTICES OR THIS FILE HEADER.
 *
 * This code is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
 * under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 only, as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation.  Oracle designates this
 * particular file as subject to the "Classpath" exception as provided
 * by Oracle in the LICENSE file that accompanied this code.
 *
 * This code is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
 * ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU General Public License
 * version 2 for more details (a copy is included in the LICENSE file that
 * accompanied this code).
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License version
 * 2 along with this work; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
 * Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301 USA.
 *
 * Please contact Oracle, 500 Oracle Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA 94065 USA
 * or visit www.oracle.com if you need additional information or have any
 * questions.
 */

package com.sun.javafx.binding;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.WeakListener;
import javafx.beans.binding.Binding;

public class BindingHelperObserver implements InvalidationListener, WeakListener {

    private final WeakReference<Binding<?>> ref;

    public BindingHelperObserver(Binding<?> binding) {
        if (binding == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Binding has to be specified.");
        }
        ref = new WeakReference<Binding<?>>(binding);
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
        final Binding<?> binding = ref.get();
        if (binding == null) {
            observable.removeListener(this);
        } else {
            binding.invalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean wasGarbageCollected() {
        return ref.get() == null;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the listener instance that's added to the dependencies (i.e. the `Observable`s) is a `WeakListener` and only maintains a weak reference to the `Binding`. This allows the `Binding` to be garbage collected even if it hasn't been properly disposed. This is done to help prevent a memory leak in the case the `Binding` has fallen out of scope but the `Observable`s haven't.

In other words, the `Observable` maintains a strong reference to the `InvalidationListener`, but the `InvalidationListener` maintains a weak reference to the `Binding`.

---

This sort of behavior is documented in "remote" places, including [`Property#bind(ObservableValue)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/beans/property/Property.html#bind(javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue)):

> Create a unidirection binding for this `Property`.
>
> Note that JavaFX has all the bind calls implemented through weak listeners. This means the bound property can be garbage collected and stopped from being updated.

And [`Binding#dispose()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Binding.html#dispose()):

> Signals to the `Binding` that it will not be used anymore and any references can be removed. A call of this method usually results in the binding stopping to observe its dependencies by unregistering its listener(s). The implementation is optional.
>
> All bindings in our implementation use instances of `WeakInvalidationListener`, which means usually a binding does not need to be disposed. But if you plan to use your application in environments that do not support `WeakReferences` you have to dispose unused `Binding`s to avoid memory leaks.

*Note: The implementation doesn't appear to use `WeakInvalidationListener`, but the effect is the same.*